# XC8 error undefined symbols

Tags: c, timer, microchip, xc8

I've gone through the questions already asked and can't seem to find any relating to this.

I'm trying to use the timer interrupts on my PIC18F8722 and keeps on giving the error:

```
:: advisory: (1233) Employing 18F8722 errata work-arounds:
:: advisory: (1234)  * Corrupted fast interrupt shadow registers
:: warning: (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode
:0: error: (500) undefined symbols:
_ReadTimer0(dist/default/production\ultrasound.X.production.obj)       _OpenTimer0(dist/default/production\ultrasound.X.production.obj) _CloseTimer0  (dist/default/production\ultrasound.X.production.obj) 
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:135: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/ultrasound.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/MPLABXProjects/ultrasound.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:78: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/MPLABXProjects/ultrasound.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/ultrasound.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)

Not sure what's wrong cause it doesn't give a definite solution and it works perfectly fine on a second program I had written running a pwm which uses the same timer and compiler on the same system.

Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code

```
#include "p18f8722.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <timers.h>
#include <delays.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int z,b=0;signed char val=0;

void interrupt time(){
    if(INTCONbits.INT0IF){
        INTCONbits.INT0IF=0;
        z = ReadTimer0();
        CloseTimer0();
        b = 1;
    }
}

void en_int(){
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.INT0IE = 1;
    INTCON2bits.INTEDG0 = 1;
}

void con_timer(){
    OpenTimer0(TIMER_INT_OFF & T0_16BIT & T0_SOURCE_INT & T0_PS_1_8);
}

void main(void){
    ADCON1 = 0x0F;
    TRISBbits.RB0 = 1;
    TRISF = 0x00;
    TRISA = 0x00;
    LATAbits.LATA4 = 1;
    en_int();
    while(1){
        LATAbits.LATA2 = 0;
        Delay1TCYx(5);
        LATAbits.LATA2 = 1;
        Delay1TCYx(25);
        LATAbits.LATA2 = 0;
        con_timer();
        while(!b);
        b = 0;
        val = (char)(z/58.3);
        LATF = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your linker script including correct libs? Did you try to cean up the project? Remove all .cod .cof .hex .lst  files and rebuild it.

Comment: Use #include <xc.h> instead of #include <p18f8722.h>
That said, do you do a "clean and build?"